# How can I switch my python between CMD and PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, interpreter

I discovered that my python is running on PowerShell, so I want to change it to CMD if that's possible.
but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Just open CMD and run your python program through there....?

Answer (score 0):

you can open a `cmd` window and run python from there.

you can also write `cmd` on `PowerShell` and it will change to `cmd`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IDE like, say, VSCode, you can select the terminal you want to use drop a drop-down menu in the terminal itself or in the settings file.

If you're running python scripts by double-clicking on the files, you can choose "open with" and select command as the default.

Answer (score 0):

- Do `win + R` combination
- Type `cmd` and enter
- Type `python` in the terminal

Or I found out that if powershell is your default and you are on Windows 10, replace powershell with CMD by following this:

> Open Settings > Personalization > Taskbar. Now, turn the “Replace Command Prompt with Windows PowerShell in the menu when I right-click the Start button or press Windows key+X” option to "Off"